# Unable to pass a second param in query

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, neo4j

The following query works fine.

```
interface MyRepository : Neo4jRepository<Character?, Long?> {
    @Query("MATCH (c1:Character)-[:positive]->(c2:Character) WHERE c1.id = \$id RETURN c2")
    fun findRelations(relation: String, id: Long): List<Character>
}
```

But I want to pass that relation as a param too.

But when I perform this I end up with errors.

```
interface MyRepository : Neo4jRepository<Character?, Long?> {
    @Query("MATCH (c1:Character)-[:\$relation]->(c2:Character) WHERE c1.id = \$id RETURN c2")
    fun findRelations(relation: String, id: Long): List<Character>
}
```

The error.

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:
> Invalid input '$': expected "%", "(" or an identifier (line 1,
> column 24 (offset: 23))\n"MATCH
> (c1:Character)-[:$relation]->(c2:Character) WHERE c1.id = $id RETURN
> c2"\n                        ^; Error code
> 'Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError

So I tried with % as suggested. That throws error too. `\%` throws compilation error thus using double `\\`.

```
interface MyRepository : Neo4jRepository<Character?, Long?> {
    @Query("MATCH (c1:Character)-[:\\%relation]->(c2:Character) WHERE c1.id = \$id RETURN c2")
    fun findRelations(relation: String, id: Long): List<Character>
}
```

The error.

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:
> Invalid input '\': expected "%", "(" or an identifier (line 1,
> column 25 (offset: 24))\n"MATCH
> (c1:Character)-[:\%relation]->(c2:Character) WHERE c1.id = $id RETURN
> c2"\n                         ^; Error code
> 'Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError

What am I missing, what is the syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypher does not support dynamic relationship types in a *path pattern*. Nevertheless, you still can use dynamic relationship types in a Cypher query (although it will not be efficient).

This should work work you:

```
@Query("MATCH (c1:Character)-[r]->(c2:Character) WHERE TYPE(r) = \$relation AND c1.id = \$id RETURN c2")
```